# Where is the Coordination Center of Muslims of the North Caucasus located? And who runs it?

Tags: russian-federation, islam, antisemitism, 2023-israel-hamas-war, caucasus

I'm confused by [this](https://www.rferl.org/a/russia-daghestan-airport-stormed-anti-jewish-protesters-passengers/32658899.html):

> Daghestani officials accused "enemies of Russia" of instigating the anti-Semitic sentiments after the Coordination Center of Muslims of the North Caucasus called on authorities to prevent refugees from Israel from entering the republic, according to the Caucasian Knot publication.

Where is this "Coordination Center" located and how is it related to "enemies of Russia"?

Answer (score 10):

[This is their website](https://kcmsk.ru/). Here is part of ["about us"](https://kcmsk.ru/struktura/kratkaja-informacija-o-kcmsk/)

> The Coordination Center for Muslims of the North Caucasus is a centralized religious organization that unites on a voluntary basis Muslim centralized religious organizations operating in the territory of the North Caucasus.

Currently, the KCMSC includes the following organizations:

- Spiritual Board of Directors of the Republic of Adygea and Krasnodar Territory;
- Spiritual Council of the Republic of Dagestan;
- Spiritual Board of the Republic of Ingushetia;
- Muslim Spiritual Board of the Kabardino-Balkarian Republic;
- Spiritual Board of the Republic of Kalmykia;
- Spiritual Board of Muslims of the Karachay-Cherkess Republic;
- Spiritual Board of the Republic of North Ossetia-Alania;
- Spiritual Administration of the Stavropol Territory;
- Spiritual Council of the Chechen Republic.

The Chairman of the KCMSC is currently the Chairman of the Muslim Spiritual Board of the Karachay-Cherkess Republic, holder of the Order of Friendship and Honor Berdiev Ismail-Hadzhi Alievich.

The highest body of the Coordination Center for Muslims of the North Caucasus is the Council of the KCMSC, formed from the chairmen (muftis) of Muslim centralized religious organizations - members of the KCMSC.

KCMSC carries out its activities in accordance with the Constitution of the Russian Federation, the Federal Law “On Freedom of Conscience and Religious Associations”, laws and other regulations in force on the territory of the Russian Federation. KCMSC is guided in its activities by the teachings based on the revelation of the Almighty - Al-Quran, the sunnah of the Messenger of Allah Muhammad (pbuh) and the norms of Sharia expressed in the traditional teachings of the imams of the North Caucasus - Hanafi and Shafi'i.

Comment: So why would they encourage the storming of an airport "in accordance with the Constitution of the Russian Federation"?

Comment: sorry, I tried to add more info but in middle of writing SE website turned it into a published post automatically!! (that is happened many times ). In reg to your comment, KCMSC have published an statement in their (1.2M members) Telegram channel (and I think in their website as well) about this and they claimed we don't encourage anyone to ...

Comment: [See this](https://socialbites.ca/latest-news/408318.html)

Answer (score 8):

- Coordination Center of Muslims of the North Caucasus seems to be a genuine Russian Federation organization and not a psy op, judging from the large picture of Vladimir Putin on [their web site](https://kcmsk.ru/novosti/ismail-hadzhi-berdiev-pozdravil-prezidenta-rf-vladimira-putina-s-dn-m-rozhdenija/) among other things.
- The advice that they give makes sense. People of North Caucasus muslim republics of Russian Federation are obviously very pro-Palestine, hence it makes sense for any ethnic Jews to avoid travelling to these regions for the duration, and ones who are already there to maintain a low profile. It will also reassure the locals against the "Israeli refugees" psy op.
- The "enemies of Russia" is chiefly the Telegram channel "[Morning Dagestan](https://t.me/utro_dagestan)" which pushes the anti-semitic narrative and Israeli refugees hoax and which did the campaign against Makhachkala Airport and its acceptance of [WZ-4728 flight](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/wz4728) from Tel-Aviv.
- That anti-semitic, pogrom-inducing channel seems to be run by a notorious anti-war activist, Russian democratic opposition member [Ilya Ponomarev](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B2,_%D0%98%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) - referred in the question as "enemy of Russia". I hope the channel link above is correct.
- The problem seems to not be restricted to Russia. Currently, 3rd most watched flight on Flightradar24 is UZB301 Tashkent to Tel-Aviv - I assume it is watched by Uzbekistan's pro-Palestinean anti-Israeli muslim population.
- Another interesting question is why WZ-4728 flight exists at all. At present there are direct flights from Tel-Aviv to just four Russian airports - Moscow, resort destinations of Sochi and Caucasus Mineral Waters, and Makhachkala, Dagestan. My take is that it is used by muslims of North Caucasus to travel to Jerusalem (a major city of muslim faith), for Israel's muslim population and Palestineans to travel to Caucasus and vice versa. So it would mean that Dagestani muslim were aggravated against an airplane mostly full of other muslim. That's why Israel-Egypt planes are [non-descript and not announced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Sinai), I guess.

Comment: Strong claims. Any proof Ponomarev is behind "Morning Dagestan" and the calls to storm the airport? Wikipedia doesn't mention any association. (OTOH it would be classic FSB psy ops to blame the democratic opposition for this, or Ukraine in this case.)

Comment: Actually, you're probably correct to some extent "Ponomarev stated on Sunday that he had not controlled the channel for more than a year.", https://www.ft.com/content/3c1d6bc8-f569-4ce7-aa87-aa59f49363e8

Comment: "My account was hacked" moment. Personally, I do believe that *some* of Russian democratic opposition in exile are FSB RF.

Comment: It became much more of an int'l brouhaha now https://www.bbc.com/news/world-67267339

Comment: "hacked". Yeah, even that BBC story cast doubt that he wasn't in control more recently, given his other claims. OTOH Pono has the tendency to make some hard to believe claims like basically taking responsibility for Dugina and Tatarsky's killings. There's even a Skeptics Q about his claims in re not in control https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56243/did-ilya-ponomarev-confess-that-he-is-behind-the-antisemitic-mobs-in-dagestan

Comment: @Fizz He is also presumed to be behind a far right manifesto that saw some limited circulation a few months ago. If that is true, it makes him an intersectional coercer.